# How can I automatically replace subscripts and highlight GoTo labels?

Tags: macros, formatting, listings, fancyvrb

I have to show a lot of autogenerated code throughout my document.

The generated code represents loops with explicit block labels and `goto`s. The following code applies function `f` to each element of an array yielding a new array (i.e. `ys = map f xs`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}

init_2:
  i_1 = 0
  arr_2 = newArray (length arr_1)
  goto guard_2

guard_2:
  guard i_1 < length arr_1 | done_2
  goto body_2

body_2:
  elt_1 = readArray arr_1 i_1
  elt_2 = f_2 elt_1
  writeArray arr_2 i_1
  i_1 := i_1 + 1
  goto guard_2

done_2:
  return arr_2

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Seeing underscores and integer suffixes everywhere is not very readable. I'd much prefer something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true, basicstyle=\ttfamily]

$\color{red}{init_{ys}}$:
  i$_{xs}$ = 0
  arr$_{ys}$ = newArray (length arr$_{xs}$)
  goto $\color{red}{guard_{ys}}$

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Nicely formated code]

However, this requires tediously formatting each listing individually. I was wondering if there is a more automated solution?

---

My question is whether it is possible to do one or more of the following in a listing:

1. Automatically subscript part of the symbol after underscore (I have a partial solution below)
2. Automatically replace `_1` with `_xs` and `_2` with `_ys`
3. Automatically markup matching strings, e.g. make labels `init_1`, `guard_2` bold

I don't mind using a different listings package if it lets me typeset code more easily.

---

I have managed to partially solve question 1 with the help of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150914/61985) answer but it only works for regular text, not listings code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

%% Automatically make code after underscore subscripted
\def\SubscriptWord#1 {\check#1\relax\textsubscript{#1} }
% Check function parses world until space/newline
\def\check#1{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
\ifcat a#1%
\else
\typeout{illegal character #1}%
\fi
\expandafter\check
\fi}

\begin{document}

\catcode`\_=\active
\def_{\SubscriptWord}

normal_foo

\begin{lstlisting}
listing_bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you are after `\lstset{...}`, setting all options to `\begin{lstlisting}` only once and they will apply as long you override them locally or use another `\lstset`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX -- you have multiple questions in your posts. This makes it a little bit difficult the answer them all in a row

Comment: The closest I got with `\lstset` was this: `\lstset{moredelim=[is][\textsubscript]{\_}{\ }}`. It doesn't always work and is (unsurprisingly) very picky about trailing spaces.

Comment: While it might be a good training to implement this in TeX: With respect to time-to-results I would also consider a pearl/python/sed script that does the "tediously formatting each listing" for you.

Comment: @Daniel If not for Jubobs answer I would've probably resorted to that. However, I really didn't want to modify the listings in tex sources, because it makes them so much harder to read and maintain.

Comment: Well, @Jubobs `listings` hacks are just amazing :-)

Comment: @Daniel But they remain dirty hacks... No regexp available, sadly. I'm thinking of learning Pygments and start writing "lexers", when needed.

Comment: @Jubobs: Well, I certainly would prefer you learning Lua and extending `listings` for Lua-based lexers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Automatically subscript part of the symbol after underscore

That could lead to problems, though; in particular, what if an identifier contains an underscore?

> 2. Automatically replace `_1` with `_xs` and `_2` with `_ys`

I think [Horst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200639/21891) is definitely on the right track. Even though I'm not a big fan of it, the `literate` key can be put to good use, here.

> 3. Automatically markup matching strings, e.g. make labels init_1, guard_2 bold.

Do you mean "Goto labels"? Highlighting those automatically with `listings` is a tougher nut to crack. What follows is more of a glorified hack than a proper solution, but see if it works for you.

[image]

---

### Breakdown of the solution

#### Package loading

Nothing very interesting here, aside from the fact that you need the `fixltx2e` package (because it defines the `\textsubscript` macro).

```
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

#### Style definitions

```
\colorlet{gotolabel}{red}
\newcommand\lstsubstyle{\itshape\rmfamily}
\newcommand\gotolabelstyle{\itshape\rmfamily\color{gotolabel}}
```

#### Listing settings

We use `columns=flexible` here instead of the default `columns=fixed`; otherwise, the output looks quite ugly. We define a one-line delimiter starting by `goto␣`. Finally, we define a number of literate replacements for subscripts, for two consecutive spaces, and for the colon character.

```
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\upshape\color{black},
  columns=fullflexible,
  moredelim=**[il][\processgoto]{goto\ },
  moredelim=**[il][\processpipe]{\ |\ },
  literate={_1}{{\lstsub{xs}}}1
           {_2}{{\lstsub{ys}}}1
           {\ \ }{\processtwospaces}2
           {:}{\processcolon}1,
}
```

#### Switch

The following switch will be used as state variable and will tell us when to activate/deactivate certain styles.

```
\newif\ifgotolabel
```

#### `EveryPar` hook

At the beginning of every "true" line, we apply the style of GoTo labels and we set the switch to true.

```
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{EveryPar}{%
  \let\lst@thestyle\gotolabelstyle%
  \global\gotolabeltrue%
}
```

#### Helper macros

Here, we define the macros used in the values passed to the `moredelim` and `literate` keys.

Every time `goto␣` is encountered, we print it normally, but we trigger the style associated to GoTo labels; no need to set the switch (it was already set at the beginning of the current line).

```
\newcommand\processgoto{%
  \lst@CalcLostSpaceAndOutput%
  {\lst@basicstyle goto\ }\gotolabelstyle%
}
```

Same idea for every occurence of `␣|␣`:

```
\newcommand\processpipe{%
  \lst@CalcLostSpaceAndOutput%
  {\lst@basicstyle\ |\ }\gotolabelstyle%
}
```

The following macro typesets subscripts in the corresponding style and applies the color of GoTo labels only if the switch is set.

```
\newcommand\lstsub[1]{%
  \textsubscript{%
    \ifgotolabel%
      \color{gotolabel}%
    \fi
    \lstsubstyle #1%
  }%
}
```

The following macro leaves two consecutive spaces occuring in "processing mode" unchanged, but reactivates the basic style and unset the switch. In particular, it is invoked at the beginning of each line that is indented by two spaces.

```
\newcommand\processtwospaces{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
    \lst@basicstyle%
    \global\gotolabelfalse%
  \fi
  \ \ %
}
```

Same idea here, but for the colon character.

```
\newcommand\processcolon{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
    \lst@basicstyle%
    \global\gotolabelfalse%
  \fi
  :%
}

\makeatother
```

---

### Complete code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Define styles for GoTo labels and subscripts
\colorlet{gotolabel}{red}
\newcommand\lstsubstyle{\itshape\rmfamily}
\newcommand\gotolabelstyle{\itshape\rmfamily\color{gotolabel}}


% 
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\upshape\color{black},
  columns=fullflexible,
  moredelim=**[il][\processgoto]{goto\ },
  moredelim=**[il][\processpipe]{\ |\ },
  literate={_1}{{\lstsub{xs}}}1
           {_2}{{\lstsub{ys}}}1
           {\ \ }{\processtwospaces}2
           {:}{\processcolon}1,
}

\newif\ifgotolabel

\makeatletter

\lst@AddToHook{EveryPar}{%
  \let\lst@thestyle\gotolabelstyle%
  \global\gotolabeltrue%
}

\newcommand\processgoto{%
  \lst@CalcLostSpaceAndOutput%
  {\lst@basicstyle goto\ }\gotolabelstyle%
}

\newcommand\processpipe{%
  \lst@CalcLostSpaceAndOutput%
  {\lst@basicstyle\ |\ }\gotolabelstyle%
}

\newcommand\lstsub[1]{%
  \textsubscript{%
    \ifgotolabel%
      \color{gotolabel}%
    \fi
    \lstsubstyle #1%
  }%
}

\newcommand\processtwospaces{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
    \lst@basicstyle%
    \global\gotolabelfalse%
  \fi
  \ \ %
}

\newcommand\processcolon{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
    \lst@basicstyle%
    \global\gotolabelfalse%
  \fi
  :%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}

init_2:
  i_1 = 0
  arr_2 = newArray (length arr_1)
  goto guard_2

guard_2:
  guard i_1 < length arr_1 | done_2
  goto body_2

body_2:
  elt_1 = readArray arr_1 i_1
  elt_2 = f_2 elt_1
  writeArray arr_2 i_1
  i_1 := i_1 + 1
  goto guard_2

done_2:
  return arr_2
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an amazingly detailed answer, thank you so much for your efforts. The solution almost gets me there, I only needed to add extra code to match labels after `|` (see `guard` block).

Comment: @roldugin Could you edit your question to better illustrate what's missing from my answer?

Comment: I just meant that `done_2` of the line `guard i_1 < length arr_1 | done_2` needs to be typeset as label as well.

Comment: @roldugin Just to clarify, is the rest of the line after a `|` always a GoTo label?

Comment: Yes after `|` to end of line. I have one more question though. To typeset a label you change text style and then reset it to `basicstyle`. This works if the label is typeset with colour or text style (as per my question). However, I wanted to use a rounded box from `tcolourbox` package around labels. The command (after defining it) is `\roundedbox{body_xs}`. Can your solution be easily adapted to that? If it's too much of a hassle I'll make do with just typeset text. Thanks again!

Comment: @roldugin Hmmm... Automatically drawing a box around GoTo labels would be more difficult; I don't know how it could be done. I wouldn't use `tcolorbox` for that, anyway.

Comment: Yes, time is of essence and I'm happy to go ahead with this result. Thank you for help and the prompt replies!

Comment: I've turned `\lstset` into `lstdefinestyle` but the hooks are still affecting all listings. Is there a way to only enable them for the new language definition?

Comment: @roldugin Yes, but it's a bit complicated; you should probably ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\lstset`, there is the option `literate` to replace underscores with the latex-markup or `_1` with `_xs` (should answer both Q1 and Q2). And use `keywordstyle` to bold keywords (if I got your point).You could try something like

```
\lstset{%
    keywordstyle=\bfseries
    literate=*{_}{\_}1
        {_1}{\_{xs}}2
        {_2}{\_{ys}}2    
}
```

Literate is very about correct brackets, so my example will not work, I suppose. Read the section 5.4 Literate programming in http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf and maybe try to find the right way. This forum has also a lot about it.
(And it has a bug about brackets, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149203)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks! I played around with it before studying Jubobs answer and after a lille fiddling it did indeed solve Q1 and Q2! `literate={_1}{{\textsubscript{$xs$}}}2`