# Figure file name as item of tcbitemize enviroment in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to insert a figure as a item of tcbitemize enviroment in tcolorbox.
The following code does work:

```
\newcommand{\ff}[2][]{%
  \tcbitem[#1]\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{#2}
}
```

usage example: `\ff[colback=red]{myfigure.jpg}`

But, the figure document name has to be enclosed in a pair of braces.
Is there a better way to use \ff like this:

```
\ff[colback=red] myfigure.jpg
```

MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}
  \tcbitem some text
  \ff[colback=red] myfigure.jpg % directly document name without braces
  \tcbitem some text
  \tcbitem some text  
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: arguments should be in braces in latex. Trying to avoid this will only lead to confusing code. Don't do it.

Comment: The argument of \tcbitem, or the content of \tecbitem need not braces. So I'd like to add figures as the argument of \tcbitem without braces. Is it possible?

Comment: `\tcbitem` does internally  `\end{tcolorbox}\begin{tcolorbox}`, it doesn't grab the following text as argument.  And yes it is possible. But don't do it.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: You could start with the code in the answers here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150909/how-can-i-parse-the-first-word-in-a-token-stream-token-by-token. And no, I won't adapt the code for you. Imho your idea is not sensible. If you want to do it, you will have to figure it out without my help.